# Highcharts series hover state enables after adding series

Tags: highcharts

If I programmatically add a series to a graph that already has hover disabled it will enable it.  I cannot seem to disable it after adding a new series.

I have recreated the code here https://jsfiddle.net/alexros/cxeh0po8/1/
hover over the series on load and see that it remains static. then click add series then hover over the series, they will go to transparent. Is this a bug or should I be calling a function after everything to reset it?

```
// create the chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                   enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

// activate the button
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
    chart.addSeries({
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    });

    e.target.disabled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also disable inactive state:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        },
        inactive: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hL4bx91e/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.inactive